# \copy command is not working to import csv table into my AWS database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to import a csv table into my cloud database on AWS. 
I'm using Dbeaver to connect to my database 
the COPY command is not allowed by AWS so I must use \copy

```
\copy orders from 'C:\tmp\orders.csv' with DELIMITER ',';
```

Dbeaver returns an error

```
Reason:
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
  Position: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Double the backslashes to escape them.

```
\copy orders from 'C:\\tmp\\orders.csv' with DELIMITER ',';
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work, I think the problem is with the \copy command itself..

Answer (score 0):

\COPY is a psql command and not a SQL statement, you need to use native Dbeaver command or connect to the database with the psql client.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY